# A method that calculates win streaks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have the following:

- A `win_streak` column on the `User` table.
- This method in `game.rb`

I'm interpreting `win_streak` as follows:

- The number if the number games in the streak
- The value (positive or negative) specifies whether those games were wins (positive) or losses (negative)

***game.rb:***

```
def adjust_streak
  u = self.user
  case self.result
    when 'Win'
      u.win_streak > 0 ? u.win_streak += 1 : u.win_streak = 1
    when 'Loss'
      u.win_streak > 0 ? u.win_streak = -1 : u.win_streak -= 1
    end
  u.save
end
```

I'm looking for a cleaner, and more succinct way to do this (e.g. keep track of win/loss streaks).

Comment: Can there be a draw?

Comment: The way the game is set up, no, there cannot be a draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use [Array#min](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/array#method-i-min) and [Array#max](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/array#method-i-max) to calculate the win/lose streak;
- You don't need to use `self` on getters;
- And you can use `user.update` instead of assigning and calling `.save`;
- I would also rename the `win_streak` column to `streak`;

---

```
def adjust_streak
  streak = case result
           when 'Win'  then [user.streak, 0].max + 1
           when 'Loss' then [user.streak, 0].min - 1
           end

  user.update streak: streak
end
```

Comment: This is solid. I really like the ingenuity of using Array#min and Array#max. I wouldn't have even thought of that. Very clever! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! `[0, streak].max + 1` and `[0, streak].min - 1` might be even clearer.

Comment: great idea @EricDuminil, I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Can the result be a tie? If not, then you can store wins and losses as Boolean values.

Thus you can use reduce the method to:

```
def adjust_streak
  u = self.user
  self.result == 1 ? u.win_streak += 1 : u.win_streak = 0
  u.save
end
```

If the result is a 'Win' (1/true) then increment the win streak, otherwise if the result is a loss the win streak is 0.

> The value (positive or negative) specifies whether those games were wins (positive) or losses (negative)

This can be the sum of the result column if you are saving the values as 1 and 0.

Comment: The problem is that I also need to know how many losses in a row the user has, if they've lost multiple games in a row. (I guess I should probably rename the `win_streak` column to just `streak`)

Comment: If the streak is LLWLL, what number would you want to show and why?

Comment: -2, to indicate that the user is on a 2 game losing streak. It doesn't necessarily have to be -2 I guess. But I would have to somehow know that the user is on a 2 game losing streak. I'm not sure how I would get that info from the sum of the result column like you said.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with a bunch of options, but kept coming back to the structure you have. So here are a couple tweaks you could apply:

**Make the logic in the cases look more alike / easier to reason about:**

```
def adjust_streak
  u = self.user
  case self.result
    when 'Win'
      u.win_streak > 0 ? u.win_streak += 1 : u.win_streak = 1
    when 'Loss'
      u.win_streak < 0 ? u.win_streak -= 1 : u.win_streak = -1
    end
  u.save
end
```

**Could use `#positive?`/`#negative?`:**

```
def adjust_streak
  u = self.user
  case self.result
    when 'Win'
      u.win_streak.positive? ? u.win_streak += 1 : u.win_streak = 1
    when 'Loss'
      u.win_streak.negative? ? u.win_streak -= 1 : u.win_streak = -1
    end
  u.save
end
```

**DRY up assignment (assumes result can only be "Win" or "Loss"):**

```
def adjust_streak
  u = self.user
  u.win_streak = case self.result
    when 'Win'
      u.win_streak.positive? ? u.win_streak + 1 : 1
    when 'Loss'
      u.win_streak.negative? ? u.win_streak - 1 : -1
    end
  u.save
end
```

As you mentioned in the comment on the other answer, the column name should be `streak` instead of `win_streak`.